# What is the correct way to convert a csv file with text to recordIO format?

Tags: python, csv, protocol-buffers, record, amazon-sagemaker

I need to convert my dataset (includes text format) to recordIO format. I have tried below code. However, I am unable to fix the below error. Do I need to make further changes in my data format?

```
ValueError: Unsupported dtype object on array
```

Code:

```
import io
import sagemaker.amazon.common as smac
X = df[['Subject','Body']].to_numpy()
y = df[['Label']].to_numpy()
buf = io.BytesIO()
smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(buf, X, y)
buf.seek(0)
```

Dataset example-

```
Label   Subject   Body
label a Test one  Test Body
label b Test two  Test second
```

Comment: What kind of model/algorithm (i guess training) do you want to run after this conversion?

Comment: Will be running a random forest/SVM after this.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation in "[Common Data Formats for Training](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-training.html)",
your content-type is associated with the algorithms in the following table:

| ContentType | Algorithm |
| --- | --- |
| application/x-recordio | Object Detection Algorithm |
| application/x-recordio-protobuf | Factorization Machines, K-Means, k-NN, Latent Dirichlet Allocation, Linear Learner, NTM, PCA, RCF, Sequence-to-Sequence |

Looking at the guide in documentation ([Data conversion](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/factorization_machines_mnist/factorization_machines_mnist.html#Data-conversion)), the data should be passed as arrays of numbers, not strings.

This means that an **encoder of some kind is needed** (e.g. [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) for labels precisely, but an encoding/embedding algorithm would be needed for the remaining data). Based on the result you want to achieve, you can decide what to use from a variety of methods such as [One-hot-encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), binary encoding, one-of-k-encoding or whatever or even complex word/sentence embedding algorithms.

For example, for a text classification task with RFC/SVM, it is first necessary to encode the text with more or less expressive embedding algorithms (e.g. [fastText](https://fasttext.cc/)).